# Retain select2 multiple selected dropdown values after form is submitted in the select field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 and populating dropdown options for 3 form fields from my database. As part of my form submission process, I've broken it down into two steps:

1. User inputs 3 select2 multiselect dropdown fields and then clicks the submit button.
2. When the page is reloaded after submission, the original 3 fields get disabled and populated with the previous selections.

However, what I am unable to do is the last part of populating the existing 3 fields which get disabled with the values the user selected before.

**This is my code of the 3 select2 input fields:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        const api_url = "<?php echo $base_api_url; ?>";
        var selected_banks = [];
        $("#multi_select_search").select2({
            placeholder: 'Choose banks...',
            ajax: {
                url: api_url + "/banks_list?query_type=bank_name",
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        query: params.term,
                    }
                    return query;
                    },
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "GET"
                },
        });
        $("#bank_account_search").select2({
            placeholder: 'Choose bank accounts...',
            ajax: {
                url: api_url + "/banks_list?query_type=bank_account&selected_banks=",
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        query: params.term,
                    }
                    return query;
                    },
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "GET"
                },
        });
        $('#multi_select_search').on('change', function() {
            selected_banks = $("#multi_select_search").val();
            $("#bank_account_search").select2({
            placeholder: 'Choose bank accounts...',
            ajax: {
                url: api_url + "/banks_list?query_type=bank_account&selected_banks=" + selected_banks,
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        query: params.term,
                    }
                    return query;
                    },
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "GET"
                },
            });
        });
        $("#credit_card_search").select2({
            placeholder: 'Choose credit cards...',
            ajax: {
                url: api_url + "/banks_list?query_type=credit_card",
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        query: params.term,
                    }
                    return query;
                    },
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "GET"
                },
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**What I have tried:**

```
$(".compare_button").click(function() {
  .each($("#credit_card_search"), function(){
       $(this).select2('val', [1,2,3]);
  });
});
```

I tried adding the above piece of code before the end of my  code above to try populating one of these fields (as a test for whether it works) -> my plan was to replace "[1,2,3]" with the submitted $_GET array from the form submission above. But it does not work.

**What I was expecting:**

I was expecting that my "credit_card_search" multi-select dropdown will get populated with options "1", "2" and "3" when my submit button "compare_button" is clicked.

Comment: Hi gakshat. You've added a `php` tag, but I see no php in your code. afaik, if you are using ajax you don't have to submit the form and refresh the page for the user input to be accepted and handled to change elements in the page